# Web service function await until another web service function is executed

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-phone-8

I am new in Async things.I have a web service that return me (in a Windows Phone 8 app) some questions and some answers from DB( 2 functios) When a call the GetQuestions function, I put the question in a ListBox and I want for each question to return me some ansewrs ( GetAnswers method), but I want to be in the listBox like that:
Question1
Answer1
Answer2
...
Question2
Answer1
Answer2

The cod below put me in the ListBox like that
Question1
Question2
Question3
Answer1
Answer2
...

How can I stop GetQuestions method and for each questions to add in the Listbox answers?

```
      private  void PhoneApplicationPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
           ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient client = new  ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient();
           client.GetQuestionsCompleted += client_GetQuestionsCompleted;
           client.GetQuestionsAsync(ID);
    }



    void client_GetQuestionsCompleted(object sender, ServiceReference1.GetQuestionsCompletedEventArgs e)
    {

        questions = e.Result.Cast<string>().ToList();

            for(int i=0;i<questions.Count;i+=2)
            {

     Listbox1.Items.Add(questions[i]);

             ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient client2 = new ServiceReference1.Service1SoapClient();
             client2.GetAnswersCompleted += client2_GetAnswersCompleted;
             client2.GetAnswersAsync(questions[i]);
            }
    }

        void client2_GetAnswersCompleted(object sender, ServiceReference1.GetAnswersCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
          answers = e.Result.Cast<string>().ToList();

              for (int i = 1; i < answers.Count; i += 2)
                     Listbox1.Items.Add(answers[i]);

     }
```

Comment: hi is this all about displaying the question and ansower together. Async is used to if when a task takes time you don't want to wait until the task complete to do below operations , the task returns when its completed. [Async and Await](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh191443.aspx)

Comment: I understand. So, what I have to do in my case?

Comment: Sorry, I couldn't get the crux of ur question. Is this about displaying them in a listbox . did you try without calling async or await , so after the first execution is fully completed , you can do other.  if your class struct is in a way that we have answer which is linked with question you can simply group by answers using linq .